# How to find mongo string field value should be less than some value in python

Tags: python, mongodb

```
 result = db1.find({"$expr": {"$lt": [{"$strLenCP": "$name"}, 20]} I)
```

I need to find the documents with name length should be less than 20 in python `mongo` like above query.

Comment: Ok. So what is the issue with the above query?

Comment: the above query is not working

Comment: Could you post the sample collection?

Comment: { "_id" : 1, "name" : "technical manager", "status" : 2, "count" : 4864, "count_mob" : 2987, "mid" : 120 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "data warehouse analyst", "status" : 2, "count" : 36, "count_mob" : 18, "mid" : 579 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "it consultant", "status" : 2, "count" : 3615, "count_mob" : 2105, "mid" : 867 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "pg test engineer manager", "status" : 2, "count" : 0, "count_mob" : 0, "pickStatus" : 2, "mid" : 858 }

Comment: Working for me. You can see it [**here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfn1yDor7zU)